# Android как сделать кнопку возврата

Tags: android, android-button

Мне нужно сделать кнопку возврата, как при collapseActionView в меню. Ее нужно самому делать к примеру через imageView или есть какие то встроенные способы, к примеру из библиотеки обратной поддержки?

Comment: что такое *кнопка возврата*?

Comment: атрибут `collapseActionView` используется для сворачивания/разворачивания виджета вроде `SearchView`, о каком возврате и куда   идет речь в вашем вопросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Показываем кнопку с помощью `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, либо если используется сапорт либа, то `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. Далее что бы отловить нажатие на неё добавляем код:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // тут пишем код обработки нажатия
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```